Living in Germany (6 months>), working remotely for a French company- Where to pay taxes?
I would like to ask for your advice please, regarding the taxation when a person has residency and working location in two different EU country. I'm asking for my husband, he is French and he is employed by a French company. In the upcoming month we are planning to relocate in Germany where we intent to apply for a residence permit (5 years). So officially we will be residents of Germany but my husband will remain employed in France, also to add he will travel half of he year in FR.
So my question is: Where he should pay income taxes? since as the law stipulates, a person suppose to pay taxes where he has a main residence (in this case Germany) however half of the year he will be traveling in FR (back and forth).
Additionally, which might complicate is that while in Germany he will work remotely, so he might fall in a totally different category by different taxation rules?
Does anyone has any similar experience regarding the taxation rules (when living abroad) and how you've arrange it?

Does the employer have a subsidiary in Germany? That would make things a lot simpler, I think. Will you be living or will he be working within 20 km of the border? Note that the FR-DE convention does not say that you pay where you reside but rather where you work, except if you are frontalier. See https://frontaliers-grandest.eu/accueil/salaries/allemagne-france/fiscalite-en-france/statut-frontalier-non-frontalier/ But beyond taxes, there are implications on social security, retirement, etc.

Are you sure that your husband's employer approves that he works from Germany? In my experience, many if not most German companies do not generally allow their employees to work remotely from abroad and I would not be surprised if the same is valid for French companies. An employer is often responsible for the deduction and payment of taxes and mandatory insurances (e.g. health, unemployment and pensions) and it is simply too much effort to have employers working in different countries.

@jcaron Thank you a lot for your reply..no his employer doesn't have subsidiary in DE..yes we plan to be within 20, max 30km of, however still not confirmed. I think the frontalier status is for those traveling on a daily basis for a working purpose..He is even in FR working remotely (home based) and he plans to continue working the same  setting in DE..His employer is not aware of the relocation plan, yet..Maybe is an absurd question, but Is it possible he resides in DE and his employer continue paying social contributions in FR? for eg. if we arrange to balance the stay 6months per country.

If it is a temporary situation you may consider flying under the radar and simply not tell anybody. Tax and residency laws are not really cut for the modern globalized world.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Thank you so much for your reply..to be honest, I was also considering this option, although we want to avoid any potential problems that might arise if we decide to fly "under the radar". My husband even in the country where he is employed (FR), is working remotely, no one will really know whether we are in DE or FR, as long as he is executing his tasks! We wonder whether he can be half year in DE but continue paying taxes in FR.. or just declaring the yearly tax in DE..For now I'm not really sure what's the smartest and less problematic solution!


So my question is: Where he should pay income taxes? since as the law stipulates, a person suppose to pay taxes where he has a main residence (in this case Germany) however half of the year he will be traveling in FR (back and forth).

There isn't really a law that says that. Instead, there are several sets of laws (here German and French) with various triggers and conditions that make a specific transaction taxable. There isn't any universal definition of “residence” either so it's entirely possible to be deemed a resident of two countries for tax purposes or for a given source of income to be taxable in two or more countries.
Then, there are special rules and, if you are lucky (and in this case you are) a treaty between both countries to decide corner cases and avoid double taxation. The agreement between France and Germany is here.
As far as I can tell, article 13 (4) implies that your husband's income should be taxable in Germany but there are several conditions (including not staying in France more than 183 days per year). Your situation is also really borderline when it comes to determining his residence, it could come down to his citizenship but ultimately residence matters less than where you are when you work. All this only covers income from work, there are other rules for other sources of income.

Additionally, which might complicate is that while in Germany he will work remotely, so he might fall in a totally different category by different taxation rules?

I don't think there is anything like that in Germany. Instead, the main question is whether your husband's employer knows about his plan and approves it. Since the regular rules apply, having an employee physically working in Germany means additional liability for the employer, especially with respect to the mandatory insurance system or retirement pensions.
I worked briefly in a fully remote position for an employer with branches in both France and Germany and the rule they set was no more than 55 days per year outside of your country of employment, otherwise they need to hire you from their local branch (or possibly rely on another status like “posting”).

Thank you endlessly for this briefly reply, you are helping me so much. For now his employer doesn't know for the relocation plan, he is planning to be half year in DE, half in FR, but to be eligible for residency permit in DE he has to be there 183> days which means he will be obligated to declare taxes in DE I guess? If he is half/half in DE and FR does his employer can continue paying  the mandatory insurance in FR? does the 55 days rule is general rule or for a specific company? Which are the other rules for other source of income? It's so complicated in a way..THANK YOU

@user163594 It's a specific (German) company's way of dealing with this, 55 days is arbitrary, I am not sure what it's based on, others allow a couple of weeks more or a couple of weeks less but if you are in a country more than half of the time, this is almost certainly going to be a problem. Being “half of the time” in a country is just making things difficult, the employer most likely doesn't even want the trouble of finding out where they should pay what.
